# wordpress site hacked - explanation of code left?

Tags: php, wordpress

a friend's word press site was hacked and in some of the php files was left some code - does anyone know what it might mean or how to decrypt it? i.e.

What was left has been pasted here:  http://pastebin.com/LbQygAaA

Comment: This is off topic for SE. You should be able to get something if you look at http://ddecode.com/phpdecoder/, though

Comment: Questions like this are asked here quite often, and generally closed pretty quickly. The answer is almost always pretty irrelevant -- you won't learn much about the hacker from what they've left, other than they fact that they've got an obscure URL that you would be advised to leave well alone. More important is to fix the hole that they got in via. This means restoring your site to a clean state and making sure that your software (primarily Wordpress, any WP plugins you're using) are up to date on the latest version and with all security patches in place.

Comment: Thanks @Spudley - yeah closed pretty quickly and marked down:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the 'payload' data. You can decode it on [many online sites](http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/). The decoded data will be the actual code of the hack, but it's obfuscated in this way to make it less easily recognizable as such.